# Pandas: Custom fillna() function?

Tags: python, pandas, data-processing, data-wrangling

Lets say I have data like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'values': [5, np.nan, 2, 2, 2, 5, np.nan, 4, 5]})
>>> print(df)
   values
0     5.0
1     NaN
2     2.0
3     2.0
4     2.0
5     5.0
6     NaN
7     4.0
8     5.0
```

I know that I can use `fillna()`, with arguments such as `fillna(method='ffill')` to fill missing values with the previous value. Is there a way of writing a custom method for fillna? Lets say I want every NaN value to be replaced by the arithmetic middle of to previous 2 values and the next 2 values, how would I do that? (I am not saying that is a good method of filling the values, but I want to know if it can be done).

Example for what the output would have to look like:

```
0     5.0
1     3.0 
2     2.0
3     2.0
4     2.0
5     5.0
6     4.0
7     4.0
8     5.0
```

Comment: I get what you are asking. You have made a column of `[5, np.nan, 1, 2, 2, 5, np.nan, np.nan, 3]` but your `print(df)` shows only two `np.nan` values. Please fix that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ffill` and `bfill` together as follows :

```
df['values'] = df['values'].ffill().add(df['values'].bfill()).div(2)
print(df)

   values
0     5.0
1     3.0 
2     2.0
3     2.0
4     2.0
5     5.0
6     4.0
7     4.0
8     5.0
```

Just change the `df['values']` to `df` to apply over the whole dataframe!